# Python 'delete' class ids for graph theory program in tkinter

Tags: python, user-interface, tkinter

I am writing a program, that is able to create vertices and edges with 'onclick'. In my menu I have an option 'New' that should clean the canvas in order to start anew.

I am creating vertices with create_oval and as far as I understood every object gets a class id 1,2,3,... if I press now the button for new I would like them to be reset/deleted otherwise my idea how to program this isn't working. Can someone help me?
I wrote in spyder and defined a function

```
def initCanvas(self): 
    self.canvas.delete(tk.ALL)
```

it is clearing the canvas, but not the ids, what is missing/what do I have to change?

Answer (score 0):

The tkinter canvas does not re-use ids. If you create an item with an id of 1 and then delete it, the next item will have an id of 2. This is one of the reasons why the canvas has performance problems if you repeatedly create and delete many objects.